# JAVA - How to redirect to a login page after custom-filter validation fail?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, configuration

I'm have to add some extra validation to the validation process in Spring-security. I added "custom-filter" to the config xml, but when it fail redirects me to a error page, and not to login page.
I can access without problems to my "authenticationFilter" class, and I'm not having problems when my credentials are good and enter to the principal page.

My Spring-security configuration is:

```xml
<http auto-config="true" use-expressions="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/admin**" access="hasRole('ADMIN')" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/login" access="permitAll" />
    <intercept-url pattern="/**" access="isAuthenticated()" />

    <custom-filter 
        ref="authenticationFilter" 
            before="FORM_LOGIN_FILTER"
    />
    <!-- access denied page -->
    <access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
    <form-login 
        login-page="/login" 
        default-target-url="/home"
        authentication-failure-url="/login?error" 
        username-parameter="username"
        password-parameter="password"
    />
    <logout logout-success-url="/login?logout" />
</http>
```

My filter is:

```java
@Component("authenticationFilter")
public class RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter.class);

    private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Error en la validación con AD";

    private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    public RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter() {
    }

    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
    @Override
    public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
        String requestBody;
        Boolean valido = false;
        try {
            requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
            ArrayList<String> credenciales = new ArrayList<String>();
            for (String val : requestBody.split("&")) {
                credenciales.add(val.split("=")[1]);
            }

            try {
                org.tempuri.ADWS service = new org.tempuri.ADWS();
                org.tempuri.IADWS port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIADWS();

                valido = port.login(credenciales.get(0), credenciales.get(1));
            } catch (Exception ex) {
                LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
            }
            UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token;
            if (valido) {
                token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credenciales.get(0), credenciales.get(1));
                setDetails(request, token);
            } else {
                LOG.error("El usuario " + credenciales.get(0) + " no existe en AD");
                token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken("", "");
                setDetails(request, token);
            }
            return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
            throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
        }
    }

}
```

I need that when the validation of "custom-filter" fails, it redirects to the log-in page, and not throw the 401/403 default page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I found the solution for my problem.
I override the method unsuccessfulAuthentication for the  class RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter, and redirect to my login-error page.

I had made a lot of proofs, and in all the cases this was successful.

The class now is:

```java
    @Component("authenticationFilter")
    public class RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {

        private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter.class);
        private static final String ERROR_MESSAGE = "Error en la validación con AD";
        private final ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
        public RequestBodyReaderAuthenticationFilter() {
        }

        @Autowired
        @Qualifier("authenticationManager")
        @Override
        public void setAuthenticationManager(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
            super.setAuthenticationManager(authenticationManager);
        }

        @Override
        protected void unsuccessfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, AuthenticationException failed) throws IOException, ServletException {
            LOG.error("El usuario no existe en AD");
            response.sendRedirect(request.getContextPath()+"/login?error"); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
        }

        @Override
        public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws AuthenticationException {
            String requestBody;
            Boolean valido = false;
            try {
                requestBody = IOUtils.toString(request.getReader());
                ArrayList<String> credenciales = new ArrayList<String>();
                //Busco el Usu y pass enviados en el request
                for (String val : requestBody.split("&")) {
                    credenciales.add(val.split("=")[1]);
                }

                try {
                    //hago el llamado el WS
                    org.tempuri.ADWS service = new org.tempuri.ADWS();
                    org.tempuri.IADWS port = service.getBasicHttpBindingIADWS();

                    valido = port.login(credenciales.get(0), credenciales.get(1));
                } catch (Exception ex) {
                    LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, ex);
                }
                UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken token;
                if (valido) {
                    //si existe en AD, realizo la validación en el sistema
                    token = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(credenciales.get(0), credenciales.get(1));
                    setDetails(request, token);
                    return this.getAuthenticationManager().authenticate(token);
                }else{
                    throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ERROR_MESSAGE);                
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                LOG.error(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
                throw new InternalAuthenticationServiceException(ERROR_MESSAGE, e);
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly the user can login, but then in the filter you are checking some additional validations because of them the user is not authorized?
Then you have to set the

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/403" />
```

to

```
<access-denied-handler error-page="/login" />
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
I had tried with this change, but is not working. When the validation fails, the 401 - error page is showed. The thing I see is that the url that redirect is "http://localhost:8080/projectName/j_spring_security_check" may be it can help...

Comment: Can you show me the code that you implemented in the authenticationFilter?